# bypassing a colon in css

Tags: css

I'm doing some css for my form that looks like:

```
<sf:form>
     <table>
        ...
     </table>
</sf:form>
```

(according to Spring framework form tag)

I want to select this form and can't do it in traditional way:

```
sf:form { 
     property: value; 
}
```

because of the colon interpreted by css.

I know that I can add an identifier to my form, such as `id` or `class` to select it, but also it's interesting for me if there is a way to do it with some css trick. Maybe, taking the parent element of a `table` tag will take care of it? The `sf:form` could be taken as parent of a table by:

```
sf:form>table
```

But here we have this annoying colon again.

So, can I take a `table` parent tag without specifying the `sf:form` one? Or, maybe, there are another ways of dealing with such elements as colon that breaks the structure of a tag in the css case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a forward slash to escape the colon after the namespace:

```
sf\:form > table {
    property: value;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fZm28/

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762307(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Adding \  before : had no effect for me. `sf\:form { attribute: value; }` didn't help, but with `<sf:form id=form> ... #form { attribute: value; }` it's working normally. What could be the possible reasons of that?

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating what you have and let me know what browser and/or version.

Comment: Note that I've checked IE9-11, Chrome and Firefox and it works in each browser. Are you *sure* the *source in the browser* has the `sf:` still present, as in it wasn't processed out by Spring?

Comment: All due respect, but that's not an answer to the actual question, which is how to deal with namespaces in CSS selectors. It turned out you didn't *need* to take it into account, but that doesn't change the fact the question is about namespaces in CSS selectors.

Comment: Yes, I understood what the problem was about. `sf` is a prefix in Spring framework and if you look on a code in browser after your web-application compilation there will be no <sf-form> but only native <form>. So, specifying just a `form` in my css file did the trick. Thank you very much for appropriate hint.